# How to force (Javascript) datatables requests to fire in sequence?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using jQuery and DataTables in a page, which fetches data from a server and populates tables quite happily.

I need to make a change to make sure the requests from dataTables library to fetch data from the server happen in a defined order. I also need to be able to trigger the update (of all tables in correct order) when I want - so need a function to trigger the appropriate code.

I have 3 tables in my page. I've tried adding a table.fnReloadAjax() call for the next table in the callback method of the first table, that either seems to only trigger a refresh on the first two tables or not at all.

I also tried creating a function to call 3 seperate function which call fnReloadAjax() on each table in turn, but being asynchronous the order of requests to the server varies.

What I've tried, that doesn't seem to do what I was hoping. Hopefully this will give some indication of my aims:

```
firstTable= $('#firstShipment').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    ...<snip>...
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
         secondTable.fnReloadAjax();
    }
});
secondTable= $('#firstShipment').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    ...<snip>...
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
         thirdTable.fnReloadAjax();
    }
});
thirdTable= $('#firstShipment').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    ...<snip>...
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {
         //this is the last table, do nothing on completion
    }
});
```

I'd be quite happy with a solution that is either defined in the init of dataTables (what I'm trying to do above) or with a separate function I can call periodically to force an ordered update.

Comment: What do you mean by update? Do you need a dedicated update button or do you want to use built-in update mechanics (e.g. if the user changes the sorting order of a row data table calls the server automtically). The second one sounds difficult.

Comment: The aim was that the data is reloaded every n seconds. Seems to be working now with the implementation above. When the timer hits zero I call fnReloadAjax() on the first table and it won't call update on next until the callback executes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the data in a specific order and make it synchonous, you can perform the data retrieval in two steps. The 1st one, making a synchronous ajax call using the parameter *async: **false***. See:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Once you have the results, you can populate the data by using a Javascript array datasource for your datatable. See:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Curiously, I retried the implementation given in my example code above and it seems to be working in sequence everytime now.

I'm triggering a refresh when I want by calling firstTable.fnReloadAjax(), which has a call back of the same on 2nd table, which has a callback of same on third table.